# How to convert the datetime field from SQL to readable date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sql

I am getting some data from the SQL database which is in DateTime format and trying to display it on the browser but it is not being displayed in readable date-time format.It is being displayed as following:
[image]
How can I convert the Date I receive from the database to readable datetime and display it. I am using the following code to display the date:

```
items.forEach(function (entity) {

document.getElementById("auditListHolder").innerHTML =
document.getElementById("auditListHolder").innerHTML +
"<tr><th>Date Assigned:</th> <td>" + entity.DateAssigned + "</td></tr>" +
"<tr><th>Date Downloaded:</th> <td>" + entity.DateDownloaded + "</td></tr>" +
"<tr><th>Submission Due Date:</th> <td>" + entity.DateDue + "</td></tr>" ;

});
```

This gives the output as shown in the above image. How can I convert the these date fields to readable dates to display them ??

Comment: Why have you got slashes in your result?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy  No idea.. that's how I am getting the output

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: That's a fairly common convention when passing dates through JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `/Date(...)/` format is a common convention (but just convention) for passing dates through JSON, which has no concept of dates. The number is (usually) the number of seconds or milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1, 1970 GMT). So to turn those into readable dates, you would extract the number, multiply it by 1000 if it's in seconds (and it appears to be in your examples), pass that into the `Date` constructor, and then format the resulting date.

The first part (converting to a `Date`) looks *something* like this:

```
function dateFromSpecialString(str) {
    var match = /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//.exec(str),
        num = match && parseInt(match[1], 10);
    if (num) {
        return new Date(num * 1000); // Assuming num is seconds, not milliseconds
    }
    return null;
}
```